# signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: Second argument “password” must be a valid string with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a login page with react and firebase and i've come across this problem, saying that `email` should be a valid string. Here's what i did so far:

index.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './login.css';
import firebase from '../../config/firebase';
import 'firebase/auth';

const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

    const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEmail({
            email: event.target.value
        });
    }

    const senhaChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setSenha({
            senha: event.target.value
        });
    }

    const logar = () => {
        console.log(email);
        console.log(senha);
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).then(result => {
            alert('Usuário logado');
        }).catch(err => {
            alert('Algo deu errado');
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="login-content d-flex align-item-center">
            <form className="form-signin mx-auto">
                <div className="text-center mb-4">
                    <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal headerLogin">Login</h1>
                </div>

                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" onChange={emailChangeHandler} className="form-control my-2" placeholder="Endereço de email" />
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" onChange={senhaChangeHandler} className="form-control my-2" placeholder="Senha" />
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block my-2" onClick={logar} type="button">Entrar</button>

                <div className="msgsLogin text-white text-center my-5">
                    <span><strong>WoW!</strong> Você está conectado!</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span><strong>OPS!</strong> Verifique se a senha ou usuário estão corretos!</span>
                </div>

                <div className="opcoesLogin mt-4">
                    <a className="mx-2">Recuperar Minha Senha</a>
                    <span className="text-white">&#9733;</span>
                    <a className="mx-2">Quero Cadastrar</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const firebaseConfig = {
    //configuration goes here
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  export default firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

When i console.log my email and password, they appear as objects. Is that right? What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set your state as objects, when both `senha` and `email` are of type `string`, as defined on your component.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');
```

Therefore, you should be making the following changes to `senhaChangeHandler()` and `emailChangeHandler()`:

```
const senhaChangeHandler = (event) => {
  setSenha(event.target.value);
};

const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
  setEmail(event.target.value);
};
```

This way, both `senha` and `email` will be strings, and they can be parsed as valid arguments when called with `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()`.